# Hibernate Inhertance Mapping Using XMl File

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, mapping

I'm using mapping XML to create a database. I have 2 classes of `Intervention` and `Preventive`. `Preventive` contains the attributes `PeriodePreventive` and `inherits` from `Intervention`.

When I run the project I have this error

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
    (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could 
    not read mappings from resource: dao/Intervention.hbm.xml
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at dao.Service.addPARTICIPANT(Service.java:13)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not read mappings from 
    resource: dao/Intervention.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:484)
    at 
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1443)
    at 
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1392)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1368)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1288)
    at Util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid mapping
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:481)
    ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 10; 
    Le contenu du type d'élément "class" doit correspondre à " 
   (meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite- 
   id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one- 
   to-one|component|dynamic- 
   component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*, 
   ((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql- 
   update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
    at
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown 
    Source)
    at 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown 
    Source)
    at 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown 
    Source)
    at 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown 
    Source)
    atcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElemen 
    t(Unk 
    nown Source)
    atcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unkn 
   own Source)
    at 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl. 
    scanEndElement  (Unknown Source)
    at 
     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl 
    $FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown 
    Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl. 
    next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl. 
    scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration. 
    parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration. 
    parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown 
    Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser. 
    parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:421)
    ... 9 more


      <class name="dao.Intervention" table="Intervention"
        discriminator-value="TypeIntervention">
        <id name="IdIntervention" column="IdIntervention">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="DateIntervention" column="DateIntervention"></property>
        <property name="ActionIntervention"
            column="ActionIntervention"></property>
        <joined-subclass name="dao.Preventive" table="Preventive">
        <key column="IdIntervention"/>
        <property name="PeriodePreventive"></property>
        </joined-subclass>
        <many-to-one name="Anomalie" class="dao.Anomalie"
            column="IdAnomalie" />
        <many-to-one name="User" class="dao.Utilisateur"
            column="IdUser" />
     </class> </hibernate-mapping>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>  
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just moved

```
  <joined-subclass>....</joined-subclass>
```

after

```
<many-to-one>....</many-to-one>
```

at the end of the file